# Custom Settings difference between Object Name and Api Name?

Tags: customsetting, configuration

Can someone explain me what is the difference between object name and api name for custom setting. The doc says for object name :
Name used when the custom setting is referenced by formula fields, Apex, or the Force.com Web Services API.
But when I tried to access a custom setting from an Apex class using the object name it doesn't work I have to use the Api name, what am I understanding/doing wrong ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hmmmm.   I never noticed that it said that.  AFAIK, that is incorrect, and you must use the API Name to access the custom setting in Apex or via the API.  I don't think you are doing anything wrong, just an error in the documentation.

Comment: Chris, you should post that as an answer so others know this question was completed.

Answer (score 0):

In apex you must use the unique api name of custom settings only.
Custom settings are similar to custom objects that enables application developers to create custom sets of data.